# woocommerce.php doesn't override page.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, overriding, sidebar

I run into an annoying case with a custom WooCommerce site:

I have a wordpress shop, the custom theme has the woocommerce.php file which contains the code to disable sidebar on specific pages (Woo conditional tags):

```
if ( is_cart() ) {
    echo '<main class="ndm-site-main col-12" role="main">';
    woocommerce_content();
    echo '</main>';
} else {
    get_sidebar();
    echo '<main class="ndm-site-main col-lg-9" role="main">';
    woocommerce_content();
    echo '</main>';
}
```

The problem, that is doesn't work anymore. Woo pages based on page.php, woocommerce.php doesn't override it.

I've added theme support code to functions.php.

The methood above works fine in the previous sites I made, but now it simply stopped functioning. I also deleted Woo template cache, but the sidebar still visible on the cart page.

The cart page template still working from page.php. Can't figure out what am I missing and it drives me crazy! :)

Was there a Woo update that kills this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I recommend using [Query Monitor](https://querymonitor.com/)'s Template panel to see what template files are being looked for.

Comment: After checking [WooCommerce's code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-template-loader.php#L224), it looks like it does still look for `woocommerce.php` in the theme, so no, support hasn't been removed.

Comment: I use What the File plugin to check what templates are in use, and it says page.php is the one on cart page. I don't understand. And thank you Caleb for the feedback about the support code!